# Django caching image from external api

Tags: python, django, caching

I want to cache images that comes to my app from google api.

Settings (Note that I prefer using FileBasedCache):

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
        'LOCATION': CACHE_ROOT,
        'TIMEOUT': 0,
    }
}
```

Here's my code that is called whenever I want to get any photo:

```
    # Shorting later syntaxes
    photo_ref = photo["photo_reference"]
    # Setting up cache key
    cache_key = "PHOTO_IMAGE" + photo_ref
    # Getting previous cache
    cached_data = cache.get(cache_key)

    # Checking if previously cached data exists
    if cached_data != None:
        # Returning cached data
        return cached_data
    else:
        image = "IMAGE NONE"

        # Getting temp image
        URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&key=" + settings.KEY
        URL += "&photoreference=" + photo_ref
        result = urllib.request.urlretrieve(URL)
        img_temp = NamedTemporaryFile(delete = True)
        img_temp.write(urlopen(URL).read())
        img_temp.flush()

        # Saving new data to cache
        cache.set(cache_key, File(img_temp), django_settings.CACHES["default"]["TIMEOUT"])
        return img_temp
```

But this code throws me:

```
TypeError at /api/image_gallery/ChIJvxOujlf6PEcRIG3Mt57gV4A
cannot serialize '_io.BufferedRandom' object
```

Full traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /api/image_gallery/ChIJvxOujlf6PEcRIG3Mt57gV4A
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 495, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 455, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 492, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dolidod/coding/fest-apka/app/views.py", line 59, in get
    print(places_info.get_place_images_gallery(places_info, place_id))
  File "/home/dolidod/coding/fest-apka/app/scripts_for_api_control/high_level_code.py", line 135, in get_place_images_gallery
    cache.set(cache_key, File(img_temp), django_settings.CACHES["default"]["TIMEOUT"])
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/cache/backends/filebased.py", line 54, in set
    self._write_content(f, timeout, value)
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/cache/backends/filebased.py", line 44, in _write_content
    file.write(zlib.compress(pickle.dumps(value, self.pickle_protocol)))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tempfile.py", line 620, in func_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.BufferedRandom' object
[03/Jul/2019 19:26:44] "GET /api/image_gallery/ChIJvxOujlf6PEcRIG3Mt57gV4A HTTP/1.1" 500 123133
```

I think this line is the problem: `cache.set(cache_key, File(img_temp), django_settings.CACHES["default"]["TIMEOUT"])`

I think django don't know how to deal with images.

Should I convert this image somehow? If i convert it, how can I re-get this image (to show in my templates/send to my frontend framework).

Or maybe should I create my own model that will be responsible for caching (For example with fields Fields 'updated_at', 'image', 'api_reference')?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're doing all that with NamedTemporaryFile, and even less why you then wrap that in a File object before passing it to the cache. *Especially* as `urlretrieve` has *already* saved the object as a temporary file to disk; what you do for some reason is to retrieve it to disk, then take the URL and retrieve it *again*, wrapping it in a temporary file, then wrapping that temporary file in another File object. Not surprising that it doesn't work.

You could read the file that `urlretrieve` saved and pass that, but it would be pointless. Really you should be using `urlopen` instead, and pass the result of reading that direct to the cache. So it's just:

```
result = urllib.request.urlopen(URL).read()
cache.set(cache_key, result)
```

Comment: And what about serving this file, for my templates/frontend framework?

Comment: I mean... If i have image in form of python variable ( image = cache.get(cache_key)), how can I serve it? Should I save it in /media/ directory? @Daniel Roseman